# How can allocate statistic frequency to records/rows of dataframe in PySpark without using .toPandas() hackPySpark?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, normalization, feature-engineering, label-encoding

I'm a newbie in PySpark, and I want to translate the **preprocessing** including encoding and normalizing part scripts which are pythonic, into PySpark for *synthetic* data. (Columns A & C are categorical)  At first, I have Spark data frame so-called `sdf`  including 5 columns:

Below is the example:

```
#+----------+-----+---+-------+----+
#|A         |B    |C  |D      |E   |
#+----------+-----+---+-------+----+
#|Sentence  |92   |6  |False  |49  |
#|Sentence  |17   |3  |False  |15  |
#|Sentence  |17   |3  |False  |15  |
#|-         |0    |0  |False  |0   |
#|-         |0    |0  |False  |0   |
#|-         |0    |0  |False  |0   |
#+----------+-----+---+-------+----+
```

Now I want to allocate *statistic frequency* besides other features and concat the results with `sdf`. So far, I can do it using pythonic scripts:

```py
#import libs
import copy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn import preprocessing

#Statistical Preprocessing
def add_freq_to_features(df):
  frequencies_df = df.groupby(list(df.columns)).size().to_frame().rename(columns={0: "Freq"})
  frequencies_df["Freq"] = frequencies_df["Freq"] / frequencies_df["Freq"].sum() # Normalzing 0 & 1
  new_df = pd.merge(df, frequencies_df, how='left', on=list(df.columns))
  
  return new_df

# Encode and Normalize
def normalize_features(df):
  temp_df = df.copy()
  
  le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
  #le.fit(temp_df)
    
  temp_df[["A", "C"]] = temp_df[["A", "C"]].apply(le.fit_transform)
  
  for column in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]:
    #-1: all rows selected into 1 
    # reshape(1, -1) select one row contains all columns/features
    temp_df[column] = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(temp_df[column].values.reshape(-1, 1)) 
    
  return temp_df

# Apply frequency allocation and merge with extracted features df
features_df = add_freq_to_features(features_df)

#Apply Encoding and Normalizing function
normalized_features_df = normalize_features(features_df)


to_numeric_columns = ["A", "B" , "C", "D", "E", "Freq"]
normalized_features_df[to_numeric_columns] = normalized_features_df[to_numeric_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric)
#normalized_features_df
```

**Problem:** what is the best approach to translating Preprocessing *without* converting Spark dataframe to Pandas datafarame `toPandas()` to optimize the pipeline and process it 100% spark form?

The expected output is shown below in the form of a Spark dataframe:

```
#+----------+-----+---+-------+----+----------+
#|A         |B    |C  |D      |E   |Freq      |
#+----------+-----+---+-------+----+----------+
#|Sentence  |92   |6  |False  |49  |0.166667  |
#|Sentence  |17   |3  |False  |15  |0.333333  |
#|Sentence  |17   |3  |False  |15  |0.333333  |
#|-         |0    |0  |False  |0   |0.500000  |
#|-         |0    |0  |False  |0   |0.500000  |
#|-         |0    |0  |False  |0   |0.500000  |
#+----------+-----+---+-------+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark has Spark MLlib package that is designed for feature engineering and Machine Learning purpose. That being said, you shouldn't build features manually like what you're doing with Pandas. At the end of the day, you still have to use Spark to build your models, so why not start using Spark ML properly? I strongly suggest reading through few sections like [building features](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html), [building pipelines](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html), then [classification/regression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html), and few other algorithms.

Going back to your original question, this is Spark version of your sample code (I also ran it in your notebook with a little change to fit with your variables.)

```py
# this is to build "raw" Freq
sdf2 = (sdf
    .groupBy(sdf.columns)
    .agg(F.count('*').alias('Freq'))
    .withColumn('Encoding_type', F.col('Encoding_type').cast('string'))
)
sdf2.cache().count()
sdf2.show()

# this is to normalize features using MinMaxScaler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinMaxScaler

type_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='Type', outputCol='Type_Cat')
encoding_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='Encoding_type', outputCol='Encoding_Type_Cat')
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['Type_Cat', 'Length', 'Token_number', 'Encoding_Type_Cat', 'Character_feature', 'Freq'], outputCol='features')
scaler = MinMaxScaler(inputCol='features', outputCol='scaled_features')
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[type_indexer, encoding_indexer, assembler, scaler])

# Compute summary statistics and generate model
model = pipeline.fit(sdf2)

# rescale each feature to range [min, max].
model.transform(sdf2).show(10, False)

# Output
# +------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+--------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
# |Type  |Length|Token_number|Encoding_type|Character_feature|Freq|Type_Cat|Encoding_Type_Cat|features                 |scaled_features          |
# +------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+--------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
# |String|8     |0           |true         |7                |1   |0.0     |0.0              |[0.0,8.0,0.0,0.0,7.0,1.0]|[0.5,1.0,0.5,0.5,1.0,0.5]|
# |String|0     |0           |true         |0                |1   |0.0     |0.0              |(6,[5],[1.0])            |[0.5,0.0,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.5]|
# +------+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+--------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I double-checked and tested several times to see whether the PySpark  *statistic frequency* is as equal as the Pythonic version or not. and it seems It's **not** really due to you just counted the incidents but in the pythonic version, it is normalized between 0 and 1 by a simple division in function. I tried to generate some similar rows to test it you can check in the notebook. I believe that the best scenario is to create/generate Freq with normalized data, not just absolute using of `count()`. it shows how often this row /incident repeats and give us frequency of  it

Comment: I understand that later after encoding categorical columns and vectorization, we use `MinMaxScaler()` but all aim of `Freq` column is to check the rows and generate the *statistic frequency* (based on counting) between `0` and `1`. Basically is the frequency of repetition over whole rows/incidents/events. Later this will help to improve the efficiency of the clustering algorithm when there are repetitive rows/instances

Comment: Since later at the end, I will pass pre-processed `df` to PCA, I think the best practice is I just call a **function** to create `Freq` column as *statistics frequency* for each record/row and normalized between 0 & 1 and join to `df`. If you check the colab notebook, you will see that your solution does not keep all rows (especially Repeated ones that have similar features). This can cause a problem for me when I assign back the results of clustering algorithms based on the index and column and return the right rows/records.

Comment: @Mario I suppose you know what to do next? I believe you should have a pretty good starting point to develop your program in any direction you want :)